# Are there any other flair sizes?

Tags: feature-request, flair

Currently the only sizes are 208x58, which can be very limiting, especially if you have minimal column width on the site that you intend to put it on.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

I did go through the current questions related to this, but non of them had the right answers.

The flair services from the following site also don't work - they have an even bigger width than the official ones.

https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/flair

I'm actually shocked that we didn't have more options on the official flair page - having to work with just one static size is unacceptable.

Should have different width/height options.

Anyone find a solution for this yet, or opinions?

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for this now. I was thinking about this very problem the other day and I began thinking of a way I could give users the ability to *completely* customize their flair - this means:

- Choice of colors for *each and every* part of the flair
- Choice of font / typeface / style for each part
- The ability to change the size of the flair and set borders
- The ability to decide exactly what you want on the flair
- The ability to decide where each component of the flair is placed

I am pleased to present an open beta of StackImage 2:

http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/

Using this tool is as simple as dragging and dropping components onto your flair and setting their properties. When you're done, just hit 'save' and the site will give you some HTML/JS to copy-and-paste into your site. The flair will also stay up to date just like the Stack Exchange-provided flair.

Here is a screenshot of a possible design and a preview of what it would look like:

[image]

The tools are in the toolbox on the left. On the right you can see the grid where the components are placed. These represent the individual parts of the flair. You can customize them by dragging them around, changing their color, etc.

Please let me know if you find any bugs with this tool.

Comment: +1 for, basically, the *ooooooh, shiny..!* and, more seriously, that's a superb tool :)

Comment: @David: Thanks! Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a way (or an intended way) to allow a user to add the badges for multiple sites? I realise that this is likely a personal project (but seriously, if you're not a valued associate within the next six months for this and StackApplet alone I'll be disappointed in StackExchenge Internet Services, Inc) but it would be good to show rep/badges/stats from, for example, SO *and* MSO

Comment: @David: That would be cool... but that would certainly take a lot of effort.

Comment: Yeah; that was my first thought when I posted the suggestion/pseudo-feature request. And, if not, then this is ***still*** superb; a hearty thanks :D

Comment: @David: Thanks for the feedback. It's great to hear that someone actually finds my tools useful. Oh, and image-based flair is planned for very soon.

Comment: Link not working; stackimage2 dead? :')